# Reflecting Changes To Mongo DB After New Post Request - Mongoose & Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time even formulating the question properly. Hopefully it's not too confusing.

I'm building a One To Many Relations in my Mongo DB Atlas. I'm using mongoose and Nodejs.

I'm trying to create a One User to Many Entries. For now let's just say it's a one to one, to remove a layer of complexity. One User To One Entry.

All the code in the backend works, but in short the issue I have is that.
Whenever I make a post request to create a new entry, I can include the user ID that the entry belongs to in the request. But whenever I make a post request to create a new user, I can't include an entry ID in the request, because no requests exist yet for that user. When I create a new entry, mongo db doesn't automatically update the document, to add that new entry to the user associated with it. And I don't know what I need to do on my end to get it to dynamically update the users to include new entries that belong to them.

Here are my models/schemas for users and entries, so you can see the association.

USER SCHEMA

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  email: {type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  displayName: String,
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  entry: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Entry', required: true}
}, {collection: "users"});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

ENTRY SCHEMA

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const entrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: {type:String},
  body: {type:String, required: true},
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  entryImage: {type: String}
  }, {collection: 'entries'});

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', entrySchema);
```

Here are my routes for users and entries. You can see how I set up the logic for the associations

USER ROUTES

```
 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const User = require('../models/user');
 const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

 router.get('/:userId', (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.userId;

  User.findById(id)
   .select("_id email displayName password entries")
   .populate('entry')
   .exec()
   .then(user => {
      res.status(200).json({
       id: user._id,
       email: user.email,
       password: user.password,
       entry: user.entry
     })
    })
   .catch(err => {
     error: err
     })
   })


   router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
     .exec()
     .then(user => {
       if(user.length >= 1){
      return res.status(422).json({
        message: "Username already exists!"
      }); 
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if(err){
           return res.status(500).json({
           error: err
          }); 
        } else {
          const user = new User({
           _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
           email: req.body.email,
           displayName: req.body.displayName,
           password: hash
         }); 

         user.save()
          .then(data => {
            res.status(201).json({
              message: "Your user information has been saved in our records",
              id: data._id,
              email: data.email,
              displayName: data.displayName
            })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            })
           }) 
          }
         }) 
        } 
 })
 .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({error : err})
  })
 }); //End of signup post request
```

EXAMPLE OF AN ENTRY POST REQUEST
[image: new-entry-post-request]

EXAMPLE OF A USER POST REQUEST
[image: new-user-post-request]

Please let me know of you have any other questions. Thank you so much, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your schema. You specified explicitly about the `_id` field.
Your current scheme does not allow mongoose to create this id automatically.

Well, there are two options:

1. Simplest way. Simply remove `_id` field from your schema. Mongoose will automatically generate this for you in every create request.
2. If you want to specify this, pass an option to mongoose so that it can auto-generate this for you

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true },
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed the id logic, and it still worked. So you were right. I still haven't been able to auto update the user, however I discovered about mongoose hooks, like pre and post. And I hear that these hooks have the ability to dynamically update the db. I'll check them out. Thank you again

Comment: To update user, you need to pass `_id` of the record in update call.